# How do I create a button that deletes the data from mongodb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm trying to make my button functional so that it will delete the data shown by passing it's id, but right now my button is not functioning when I clicked it there's no error or anything happen.

This is the code for my list of users page:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from '../Button';
import axios from 'axios';

class DataTable extends Component {

    deleteUser(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var id = this.props.obj.id;

        axios.post('http://localhost:4000/users/deleteUser', id)
            .then((res) => {
                alert('User Deleted')
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {this.props.obj.name}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {this.props.obj.company}
                </td>
                <td>
                            <Button onClick={() => this.deleteUser}
                                className='btnsDelete'
                                buttonStyle='btn--delete'
                                buttonSize='btn--small'
                                buttonColour='red'
                            >
                                DELETE
                            </Button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}
export default DataTable;
```

and this is the code for the router:

```
router.post('/deleteUser', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.id)
    const User = await user.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id).exec();

    if (!User) {
        console.log('Failed to Delete user Details: ');
    }else {
        console.log('User Deleted')
        res.redirect('/');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you should first check in postman if any item with the id gets deleted. If it gets deleted, then you may check for the network tab in the dev console . And no need to pass e to the function

```
 const deleteUser=()=> {
       
        var id = this.props.obj.id;

        axios.post('http://localhost:4000/users/deleteUser', id)
            .then((res) => {
                alert('User Deleted')
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
    }
```